# Linq result Int error: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Below is my code:

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dt.Columns.Add("RowId");
        dt.Columns.Add("Amount");

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = "1";
        row[1] = "2000";

        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        GetRecord(1);
    }

    protected void GetRecord(int RowId)
    {
        var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
        where row.Field<int>("RowId") == RowId
        select row;

        string FetchedRowId = results.ToArray()[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

When I use this way it gives error: Specified Cast is not valid in line:

where `TableRow.Field<int>("RowId") == RowId`

But when I convert to:

```
   protected void GetRecord(int RowId)
    {
        var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
        where row.Field<string>("RowId") == RowId.ToString()
        select row;

        string FetchedRowId = results.ToArray()[0].ToString();
    }
```

it works. Why `row.Field<int>` is not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't specify that your columns are `int`s. You can specify that with the [`Add(string, Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/730zyedy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
dt.Columns.Add("RowId", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));

DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
// whether you add strings or ints here doesn't matter, it's converted
row[0] = "1";
row[1] = 2000;
```

Comment: the assignment to some value of `row[0]` will try to automatically cast/convert the value to the correct data type, this is some kind of very *latent* feature :|

Comment: Thanks it worked. Tim, when not using typeof(int), what it is considering?

Comment: @RKh the default data type is `string`.

Comment: The `GetRecord(1)` part is ok, it's just that when you do `row.Field<int>("RowId")` the mismatch between the column's type (`string`) and the type you were trying to get it as (`int`) that caused a problem.